# didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload Not working when app is killed

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, callkit

I'm facing an issue in didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload method as it doesn't fire when app is killed/terminated. But working perfectly when app is in background.

After investigating, I found some people recommend using the new version as this one is already deprecated

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
```

`DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                completion()
            })
}`

It works good but this method is only iOS 11+ so it doesn't work for iOS 9. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it like this and it works on iOS 10 and 11.

```
 //available(iOS, introduced: 8.0, deprecated: 11.0)
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: PKPushType) {
    pushRegistry(registry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith: payload, for: type) {
        // no-op
    }
}

//available(iOS 11.0, *)
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

    //your code
    completion()
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Redssie, I did that already and yes it works for iOS 11 and iOS 10 but not 9. Any idea why?

Comment: @Elsammak No, i'm sorry. I only worked on iOS 10 and 11.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will update the requirements then.